# Do wall-mounted door stoppers with embedded springs provide any advantages over versions without a spring inside them?

Tags: doors

When taking a look at the various different types of available wall-mounted door stoppers, I've noticed two main types - ones that are simply mounted to a small hole that had to be drilled, and another similar option - the difference that this second version appears to have a spring inside it. Would there be any particular advantages of mounting a springy type - would the spring in the stopper provide more protection against the stopper itself if a door was hit hard into it?

Comment: Can you provide a picture of both? I've never seen one with a spring inside of it.

Comment: The purpose of a doorstop is to stop the doorknob from punching through the drywall.

Comment: There is no change with regard to the [Best location to install floor door stop](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/105606/51306), even though they are mounted on a vertical surface instead of a horizontal one.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The difference I have noticed is the spring models are less likely to be pulled from the wall if they are hit by a stray ankle or vacuum cleaner. They will just deflect out of the way and return to the normal position. A disadvantage is some cats find it makes a great toy and will strum the spring for hours.

Comment: Small children, too.

Comment: When I was a kid I always used to play with these 

Comment: I play with them now. Goiinng Brtbrtbrtrtrtr. Goiinng Brtbrtbrtrtrtr. Goiinng Brtbrtbrtrtrtr. I wish I had some in my house, though.

Comment: @KevinMcKenzie I installed 2 within 4 feet of each other specifically so that my 2 and 1 year can each play with it and not fight. One of them actually stops a door while the other is simply out of the way and does nothing functional.

Comment: The less obvious difference is that the spring style are longer, so they can be mounted on the skirting board rather than screwed to the floor (which is nice if the floor is tiled or concrete). They need the spring because they're longer.

Comment: In addition to not pulling out from the wall, the spring deflection allows you to not curse violently when you hit your toe or ankle on one.

Comment: I always felt these were so you COULD vacuum under/near them, in addition to making them less dangerous to step on or kick.

Answer (score 3):

The spring style cushion the stop so it is not so abrupt. The cushion action reduces wear and tear on the door and hinges but the spring style don’t tend to last as long and they cost more (or that has been my experience)

Comment: The springs I've seen rested at full compression and had nowhere to go if the door slammed into them, so had zero cushioning effefct to offer.  On the other hand, they twanged very nicely if kicked or hit with a vacuum.

Comment: It sounds like we are talking about different types.

Comment: That may well be. It always vexed me why the springs were at full compression, it seems like they'd be much more useful if compressible.  But I suppose they must stop the doorknob from hitting the wall at all costs...

Comment: I was thinking about the version that have the spring load at the door knob to cushion those only last a Couple of years but don’t damage the door or hardware. The op said spring inside was my reasoning for that style.

Comment: The fully compressed type are made that way because if they had any travel they would fling a violently opened door back to the closed position without any loss of energy but with the possible loss of teeth or nasal bone.